# Received exception Bad Request: "Series could not be created as there are no occurrences in the current recurrence definition for given range

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am receiving this exception from CRM while creating a recurrence as `start date = current date`. Could you please help figure out what could be the possible miss.
CRM Exception Bad Request:

> Series could not be created as there are no occurrences in the
>   current recurrence definition for given range.

Some of the tags in request JSON as below:

```
"recurrencepatterntype": 0
starttime": "2019-05-30T10:00:00Z",
"endtime": "2019-05-30T10:30:00Z",
"patternstartdate": "2019-05-30T09:48:04Z",
"patternendtype": 2,
"occurrences": 1,
```

Tried to create Daily recurrence which ends after 1 occurrence and start date is current date.

Comment: For start date as any future date is is working fine. Only issue is when start date set to Current Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below code to create Recurrence rule and worked perfectly fine for me.

```
var entity = {};
entity.patternstartdate = new Date("05/30/2019 14:00:00").toISOString();
entity.patternenddate = new Date("05/30/2019 14:30:00").toISOString();
entity.recurrencepatterntype = 0;
entity.occurrences = 1;
entity.patternendtype = 2;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/recurrencerules", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: Thank You @AnkUser. Appreciate the response.

Comment: cool if this helps do mark it as solved would help others as well.

Comment: Tried setting properties as you mentioned for recurrence rule. However its not working for me. Error received as "Invalid Recurrence Pattern","innererror":{"message":"Invalid Recurrence Pattern","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0,. . . " :(

Comment: error states issue with Recurrence Pattern, could you post your Json here